# Does Terraform allow cross-region snapshots to be configured for Redshift Clusters?

Tags: amazon-redshift, terraform

I'm new to Terraform -- I've looked in the documentation here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/redshift_cluster.html

...but I don't see an option to enable cross-region snapshots for Redshift clusters using a Terraform template.  Seems like a simple option to implement, and a critical feature for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently not possible. Here's an [open issue asking for this feature](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/1226)

If you absolutely need to do this from terraform, you could use a `null_resource` with a local-exec provisioner and run a local script that calls [enable-snapshot-copy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/redshift/enable-snapshot-copy.html)

Comment: At least we have an option to extend.  Thanks for the confirmation and helpful response.